# Published paper not showing up on google scholar

Tags: arxiv, google-scholar

I have a paper that I uploaded to arXiv and google scholar listed it as a publication.

Since then the paper has been published in a nature journal several months ago.

The nature publication still hasn't showed up on my scholar profile, which still lists the arXiv version.

Is there any way to resolve this conflict?

Comment: Not a verified solution but it probably helps: on arXiv the function "Journal ref" allows you to add a DOI or similar qualifier (once available) to your pre-print to associate it with the actual publication. This probably helps Google with the association; and it's anyway a good thing to do for completeness (and possibly copyright).

Comment: I just experienced this bug in a new form: right after my paper appeared at a good journal, Scholar was quick to appropriately transform it from arXiv status to journal status, but 1-2 weeks afterwards that was erroneously reversed. Now it's back to arXiv status. Weird!

Comment: I'm having the same problem, 7 years after your post and 9 years after the Claus Wilke's blog post. It's kinda hilarious. Quoting one movie: "I mean, I'm smiling, but I am very fucking furious. "

Answer (score 16):

In a [blog post](http://serialmentor.com/blog/2015/10/8/Google-Scholar-bug-redux), Claus Wilke describes a bug with Google Scholar where it does not update pre-prints once the article has been publsheed. He notes that:

> 1. The bug exists
> 2. The Scholar team is aware of it
> 3. They don’t know how to fix it
> 4. They don’t think it’s a particularly pressing problem
> 5. For any given paper, the problem will go away eventually, after several months or more

The other answer by cirne recommends that you upload your own citation. This will update your Scholar Profile but not Google Scholar. Thus, your profile will be correct, but others cannot search Google Scholar to find your papers.

Comment: Are you sure Google Scholar searches don't use the profile information?

Comment: @Buzz as of the post in 2015, they did not. Based upon Claus Wilke's blog, fixing it doesn't seem to be a high priority. Additionally, he was able to ask Google's development team, but I don't know anybody on the team.

Answer (score 4):

Do you have a google scholar account? If so, you can manage these on your profile page (look for yourself in scholar and click on your name).

One way is to add a manual entry by going to your profile(click "Add" => usually it's listed there, if it isn't, click "Add Manual Entry"). In the interest of keeping your citation, you can also merge both articles (on the profile page tick the boxes next to both entries and select "Merge").

Alternatively, you can also edit the publication by clicking on the title of the publication, edit the information there to reference Nature as opposed to arXiv.

Comment: this is my method. it does get the papers into your list and you can choose whether the primarily displayed information is the arxiv.org or the publication information you entered. It is still problematic because papers that are added manually, but not automatically added in any version don't seem to increase the citation count of the articles they cite.