# Google scholar citation problem with arxiv

Tags: arxiv, google-scholar

I have a paper that I uploaded to arXiv and google scholar listed it as a publication. The paper cites a number of my papers that are already published. However, Google scholar doesn't add arxiv citations to the already published papers.

Comment: This is a little unclear to me. You say "google scholar listed it as a publication ... Google scholar doesn't recognise it". Do you mean it showed up on your profile but can't be found in a Google scholar search?  Or ... ?? A little more explanation would be helpful.

Comment: or do you mean that the arxiv paper doesn't show up in the lists/counts of citations for your other papers?

Comment: Did you find an answer to the problem you asked? I have similar issues with Google Scholar. It would be great if you provide an answer to your question if you fixed the issue.

Comment: @Millad Google scholar will eventually add the citations. It's not quite immediate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Published paper not showing up on google scholar](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/80698/published-paper-not-showing-up-on-google-scholar)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So apparently you have to wait. There is a delay between your arXiv submission and detection of its citations by Google scholar. But it will eventually happen.

Comment: Sometimes citations are missed, though. For reference, I'm currently waiting >10 months for a citation to be added to one of my papers from an arXiv preprint.

Comment: @ComputerScientist what to do for those situations?

Answer (score 3):

There is an issue where Google Scholar does not promptly add the full version of a paper to its index if a pre-print version of the same article was previously found. See the discussion below:

[Do all preprint servers have the non-updating issue in google scholar](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/95152/do-all-preprint-servers-have-the-non-updating-issue-in-google-scholar/140015#140015)

The funny thing is that the final version of the article will show up in a regular Google search but not in a Google Scholar search. Apparently it takes a while for the two version to be reconciled and merged.