# My recent paper on arxiv does not appear in my google scholar account?

Tags: arxiv, google-scholar

I posted a paper on arXiv recently. But it doesn't appear on my Google scholar account. Although it has appeared on the Google scholar accounts of my co-authors. How can I link my Google scholar account to my arXiv account or should I add this paper to my scholar account manually? Thanks.

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/80698/published-paper-not-showing-up-on-google-scholar Duplicate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [linked question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/80698/published-paper-not-showing-up-on-google-scholar) is related, but not exactly the same -- in that question, the problem is an article showing up on your profile but not listing the right venue, whereas here, the problem is that the the article does not show up on your profile at all.

In your case, the solution is much simpler: just go to your profile, click the + button, "add articles", and search the article and select it. You don't have to upload a manual citation; Google scholar allows you to associate any article with your name that you want.